# How can I find time of an insertion?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am using:

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
WHERE Operation IN ('LOP_INSERT_ROWS') AND AllocUnitName = 'dbo.HeartBeat'
```

This return some rows, but I cannot tell which column contains a date and time.

I want to know WHEN the record was inserted. The inserted record contains a TIMESTAMP provided by the user BUT I want to see if the user is actually inserting the record at the time given by TIMESTAMP

Comment: Silly me - I added a tag sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find `INSERT` time using `fn_dblog()` function looking at `[Begin Time]` column of the corresponding `begin transaction` (with `INSERT` name) in the result set.

The tricky thing here is that the column `AllocUnitName` of this row (`LOP_BEGIN_XACT`) is NULL, while `[Begin Time]` is `NULL` for rows corrensponding to `LOP_INSERT_ROWS` where `AllocUnitName`can be found.

So you should use the fact that the transaction is the same, and once you individuated the rows of interest using your query that filters for `'LOP_INSERT_ROWS'`, you should use `[Transaction ID]` to find the time:

```
select  [Begin Time]
from sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
where [Transaction ID] = '0000:cb5f3b8a' -- put here the [Transaction ID] found using your query
and Operation = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT';
```

Here is the picture illustrating what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have wrapped this in a c# method and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

`fn_dblog` shows you the data organized by Log Sequence Number (LSN). There really isn't a "time stamp" in there, because the LSN **is** the time stamp that SQL needs. All of the transactions happen in that order - the purpose here is for recovery to run and not miss a transaction to rollback/roll forward/recover.

There really is (that I know of) no translation out there for LSN to time/date. You could sort of run with a (default,default) parameter and maybe find a transaction you know for sure when happened and trace it back and do some mental gymnastics.

But really, I'd suggest something totally different. For now, take the user's word for it. But verify moving forward. Can you not put a column in that DB with a default value for the current time? Could you (don't love this, but if need this degree of logging maybe it is necessary?) set up an auditing structure with Triggers? Could you enable Change Data Capture?

There are other ways to grab this information that are far more effective than piecing together pieces and parts reading the transaction log. I'd suggest this effort be spent there.

If you insist you have a few options to narrow it down:

1. Are you using transactional replication for this database? You may be able to use some of the system tables there to help narrow it down.
2. Do you take transaction log backups frequently? Each log backup has a header and that header explains which LSNs it contains so you can at least narrow it down to a range by restoring headeronly and figuring out which backup the LSN is in and then at least know within the frequency of your log backups when that was done. `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'x:\MyLogBackup.trn'` - you can also look at the header for diffs and fulls to help narrow down if you have a needle in haystack situation.

Comment: Mike, apparently there is a function: sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time ( [Current LSN] ) BUT I get an error: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: I didn't think the cdc. tables would be populated without CDC enabled?

Comment: Is there a an easy way to check?